# grep command not filtering out , ; or '

Tags: regex, linux, grep

This is the command I'm using:

```
grep '\bth.[aeiouy]*\b' filename.txt
```

It returns things as expected like the, thee, etc. but it also returns strings like **o'th** and **with;**

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: This exact command does not match `o'th` or `with;` for me. Perhaps include a sample of your file, and the output?

Comment: I wonder if you might want the `-o` flag...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: For `o'th`, if followed by say a space, it will match because of `\b` matches a word boundary (between non-word `'` and `t`), space matched by `.` and `*` making any following vowel character optional (0 occurence of a vowel). For `with;` I can't figure out without any sample data, but looks weird.